# Multiple instances of jQuery Cycle on page (and targeting existing thumbnails with pagerAnchorBuilder)

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle, pager

I'm stuck getting multiple Cycle slideshows (with thumbnails) to work on my blog.... all of the slideshow thumbnails are targeting the first instance of the slideshow on the page, and the captions are the same on all the slideshows.

Have added a `var p = this.parentNode` but not sure how to pass it through to the onAfter and pagerFactory functions?

Thanks :)

```
// Setup cm_cycle_slideshow for each div.slideshow
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$('.slideshow #main').each(function(){
    var p = this.parentNode;
    $(this).cycle({
        fx:                    'fade',
        speed:                 500,
        before:                onAfter,
        pager:                 $('#thumbs', p),
        pagerAnchorBuilder:    pagerFactory
    }).cycle('pause');
});

function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd){
        // Update the slide caption
        $('#caption').html(this.alt);
        // Get the height of the current slide
        var $ht = $(this).height();
        // Set the container's height to that of the current slide
        $(this).parent().css("height", $ht);
}

function pagerFactory(idx, slide) { 
    return '.slideshow #thumbs span:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
}
```

And the html...

```
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="main">
<img width="470" height="313" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Camilla Meijer cushions" title="Camilla Meijer cushions" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; display: none; ">
<img width="470" height="313" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Camilla Meijer cushions" title="Camilla Meijer cushions" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; display: none; ">
<img width="470" height="313" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-medium" alt="Camilla Meijer cushions" title="Camilla Meijer cushions" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; display: none; ">
</div>
<div id="thumbs">
<span class=""><a href="#"><img width="74" height="74" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" alt="Caption here"></a></span>
<span class=""><a href="#"><img width="74" height="74" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" alt="Caption here"></a></span>
<span class=""><a href="#"><img width="74" height="74" src="blahblahblah.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" alt="Caption here"></a></span>
<div id="caption">Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a counter to identity each slideshow (and also change the IDs to classes!)

```
// Setup cm_cycle_slideshow for each div.slideshow
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
var counter = 1;
$('.slideshow .main').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().attr('id','slideshow_'+counter);
    var p = $(this).parent();
    $(this).cycle({
        element: counter, 
        fx:                    'fade',
        speed:                 500,
        before:                onAfter,
        pager:                 $('.thumbs', p),
        pagerAnchorBuilder:    function (idx, slide) {
            //console.log('#slideshow_'+counter+' .thumbs span:eq(' + idx + ') a')
            return '#slideshow_'+counter+' .thumbs span:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
        }
    }).cycle('pause');
    counter++;
});

function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd){
        // Update the slide caption
        $('#slideshow_'+opts.element+' .caption').html(next.alt);
        // Get the height of the current slide
        var $ht = $(this).height();
        // Set the container's height to that of the current slide
        $(this).parent().css("height", $ht);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with multiple duplicate IDs on the page.

Comment: I had a feeling you'd say that

Answer (score 0):

I just skipped the whole pageanchorbuilder thing, it's way to cumbersome and gives you very limited control. This is a much better option.

First build out your Cycle stage and thumb tray like this. You now have much more control over the thumbs.

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="stage">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-tray">
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
        <div class="thumb">Anything in here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use this JS to link the thumbnails to the slides. Basically, thumb 1 links to slide 1 and so on.

```
// Start Cycle
jQuery('.stage').cycle({ 
    timeout:  0,
});

// Make the thumbs change the stage on click
jQuery('.gallery .thumb').click(function(){
    var thumbIndex = jQuery(this).closest('.gallery').find('.thumb').index(jQuery(this));
    jQuery(this).closest('.gallery').find('.stage').cycle(thumbIndex);
});
```

This will work with multiple Cycle gallery's on a page no problems! Plus it's way simpler than the answer given above.